# Instrumentation test run failed

Tags: instrumentation, android-instrumentation

I would like to ask a general question,

I am doing automation testing using robotium tool with the help of a tablet which is single processor. While performing some actions my test case is failing like INSTRUMENTATION TEST RUN FAILED DUE TO JAVA.LANG.OUT OF MEMORY error.

What i need is whether the out of memory error depends on the device processor speed also or purely it depends on the app and test code.

Any solutions can help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

The OutOfMemoryError indicates that you've probably run out of heap space in the application. The device's kernel may set the limits on heap, but your problem is probably in your application and test code.

Does your test run out of memory while executing large tests?

You may want to profile your application for Memory Usage and start resolving memory leaks first.

It can also help if your robotium tests don't run for extended periods of time, but is only a band-aid if your application has memory leaks.